# Trying to modify a custom event for scroll wheel in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, listbox

I'm trying to make my ListBox auto load more items when you scroll to the bottom of it. For that I needed a scroll event.

The default listBox has no scroll event. I managed to find some code where I created a new class and inherited all the content from the default listBox. I was successfully able to add a scroll event.

The override works perfectly when the scrollbar is used by mouse click, but unfortunately will not capture the event when a scroll wheel is used.

I've tried optimizing it, so it would pick up the scroll wheel as well, but was unsuccessful.

The class I'd like to modify, so it would pick up the scroll wheel as well.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class BetterListBox : ListBox
{
    // Event declaration
    public delegate void BetterListBoxScrollDelegate(object Sender, BetterListBoxScrollArgs e);
    public event BetterListBoxScrollDelegate Scroll;
    // WM_VSCROLL message constants
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
    private const int SB_THUMBTRACK = 5;
    private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Trap the WM_VSCROLL message to generate the Scroll event
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
        {
            int nfy = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF;
            if (Scroll != null && (nfy == SB_THUMBTRACK || nfy == SB_ENDSCROLL))
                Scroll(this, new BetterListBoxScrollArgs(this.TopIndex, nfy == SB_THUMBTRACK));
        }
    }
    public class BetterListBoxScrollArgs
    {
        // Scroll event argument
        private int mTop;
        private bool mTracking;
        public BetterListBoxScrollArgs(int top, bool tracking)
        {
            mTop = top;
            mTracking = tracking;
        }
        public int Top
        {
            get { return mTop; }
        }
        public bool Tracking
        {
            get { return mTracking; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Process [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mousewheel) (and [WM_MOUSEHWHEEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mousehwheel), if needed).